# Indy multipart/form-data example

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe4

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form action="http://mysite/test.php"
      method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="text1" value="myvalue1">
    <input type="text" name="text2" value="myvalue2">
    <input type="file" name="file1">
</form>
```

How can I use this type of POST with Indy in Delphi (XE4) and get the results from it?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/11512619/80901