# Uploading files using ICS component delphi

Tags: delphi, file-upload

I am using HttpCli component form ICS to upload files using Delphi 7 ..

i copied code from example in the ICS folder .. tried to edit to let me upload files but got stuck on how to add the file to the file field name (filedata=c:\1.rar)

```
   var
 lData: TStringStream;
 lDataOut : TMemoryStream;
 lResultPage: string;
 HttpCli1: THttpCli;
 srv : string;
 Data : AnsiString;
begin
 HttpCli1 := THttpCli.Create(nil);
 lDataOut := TMemoryStream.Create;
 lData :=  TStringStream.Create('');
 //A post request would use lDataout to post data to server
 lDataOut.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
 httpcli1.SendStream := lDataOut;
 httpcli1.RcvdStream := lData;
 httpcli1.Cookie := memo2.Text;
 httpcli1.URL        := 'http://www.datafile.com/index.html';

 try
   httpcli1.get;

   //lResultPage will contain the answer from the webserver as a string
  lResultPage  := lData.DataString;

  // srv will contain upload URL ... 

   srv := ExtractBetween(lResultPage,'upload_url: "','"');

   Data := 'Filename=' + UrlEncodeToA('Chrysanthemum.rar') + '&' +
            'upload_type='  + UrlEncodeToA('file')  + '&' +
            'folder_id=0' + '&'+
            'Filedata=' + '&' +
            'Upload=' + UrlEncodeToA('Submit Query');

    HttpCli1.SendStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    HttpCli1.SendStream.Write(Data[1], Length(Data));
    HttpCli1.SendStream.Seek(0, 0);
    HttpCli1.RcvdStream      := lData;
    HttpCli1.URL             := srv;
    HttpCli1.ContentTypePost := 'application/octet-stream';

    HttpCli1.PostAsync;

 except
   lDataOut.Free;
   Exit;
 end;
 lDataOut.Free;
 lData.Free;
 httpcli1.Free ;

end;
```

this how it should be ..

[image]

So I don't know how i add the file to the "fileData" in the postdata ...

Comment: Filedata contains the file (any file) (the file supposed to be uplaoded to the server)

Comment: @KenWhite, the OP is trying to upload data, but it appears to be multipart form data.

Comment: @user3424509, I don't have an idea how to do this with ICS, but you can do this quite easily with Indy library, using TIdHTTP and TIdMultiPartFormDataStream. Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11512619/800214).